# Best way to save user profile details android app

Tags: android, save

I'm creating an app which has several users. I've created an object (user), which holds more details (name, age, custom objects etc). Because I have a custom object, I know it'll be difficult to use shared preferences. What would be the best way to store the users data? I've looked into SQLite, but I can't find a way to save custom objects into SQLite?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store objects in using any of the ORM libraries, one I would suggest is [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)

## Use SQlite with ORM

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has a Android backend which makes calls to the native Android OS database APIs to support its ORM functionality.  A number of Android developers that are using the framework successfully.  See here for more information:

> http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

In terms of many-to-many relationships, ORMLite does not support cascading or any of the more advanced ORM features but there are examples of easy many-to-many implementations:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/examples

## Use db4o with ORM

Instead of storing them in SQLite you may store them in [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/), which is specifically designed for storing objects. A simple [tutorial](http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/09/using-database-for-objects-db4o-in.html) for sotring objects using db4o.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Externalizable. Here's a blog article about it: [Externalizable](http://www.craigr.com/2011/12/23/externalizable/)

This deals mostly with making your custom object externalizable. I suspect there's a way to write these to shared preferences; I usually just send them to a file. You could make an array of user data and stream the whole thing to a file.

Comment: I was just thinking about this... Our app is an ebook reader. To save time, the program builds an array of objects that describe all the installed books. This array is serialized to a file using Externalizable. The next time the program runs it deserializes the array, then compares it to the installed books to verify nothing has changed. So the array is Externalizable, the array elements are Externalizable, and the handful of custom objects contained by the array elements are Externalizable. Works great. No databases, no third-party libraries.