# How to have android app remember user data/profile?

Tags: android

Making a app that asks user to create a profile, wondering where I should get started in having the app remember this data user inputs?  Any tutorials or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: SharedPreferences might be enough. [Another suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14471187/645270) is to use a database (SQLite being the first choice) with ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use SharedPreferences, unless you have a lot of information to store.
After the user successfully logged in, store his information in your Preferences.

For example, to store the username :

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", your_user_name);
editor.commit();
```

Each time the user accesses the login activity, you can check if the username is already stored in the preferences :

```
if (mPreferences.contains("username")) {
    // start Main activity
} else {
    // ask him to enter his credentials
}
```

When the user logs out, don't forget to delete the username key from your preferences :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.clear();   // This will delete all your preferences, check how to delete just one
editor.commit();
```

Comment: So would this be something multiple users/devices could use at the same time?  My project/assignment requries me to ultimatly create a very basic social media.  User downloads app, and creates a profile through questions, that they can log back in to see / use.

Comment: If you create a social network, that means you will have a backend application that stores users information, right ? In that case the user authentication won't be on the device but on the server, and the SharedPreferences on the device will store the information retrieved from the server. So normally there won't be any conflict between users/devices. I hope I understood you right ?

Comment: For the tutorials on SQLite (and other things in general) you can check this link, the site is my reference : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Yes that sounds good, my issue is the backend application then... SQLite for that?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that. Do you have to write it from scratch ? There are a lot of frameworks existing in different languages (Rails, Django, etc...) so it's up to you. TO communicate with the server you will have to learn about JSON communication to send and receive messages. You can find a lot of information on Google and the web site I gave you

Comment: I guess for that you will have to do some research by yourself and then you can come back and ask specific questions. If the original question on Android is answered, then can you accept it ?

Comment: Yes you have given me the most useful response, dont worry I wasn't gonna leave it "un-answered" lol

Answer (score 0):

Insert the data to a SQLite database or use a plain file. The former is recommended for big apps.

Comment: Any tutorials or where to start for SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Checked out [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  Some examples here: [SharedPreferences Tutorial](http://android4yourfuture.blogspot.tw/2012/10/android-shared-preferences-tutorial.html)

If you only have one user at once and just need to store simple user data like user name, email, id, you can store string/int/... format data in it.  Or if you have server for storing user data, you can store credentials in SharedPreference and use the credentials to get data from your server.